# How to update the number of views from the statistics module?

Tags: nodes, files

How do I change the number of reads/views from the statistics module of a node to a new number

what i want to do is match the # of views of a youtube video to a drupal website hosting the same video?

Comment: Impossible by design. Of course you can forge them if you really want, but if you imply that's the number of views of this very page, it may be penalized. In my country, if money are involved and you forge data like that, it's from half a year to eight years in prison (same for cooperation and helping with it). And if you want to separate displayed number from this page views number, well, then it's totally other question.

Comment: yes sorry, separate displayed number from this page views number. I've been able to use youtube feeder to bulk import videos but haven't been able to import user stats (like views and likes). any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Edit your question to reflect your last comment and I may look. I mean, views and stats are dynamic data that most likely are outdated just a mite after import, so it's not really supported afaik, but everything that can be seen, can be copied.